# Get all the values using $_SESSION

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have created a system where the users need to sign up with their **Name**, **Email**, and **Password**.

When they click **Submit** all of this data are sent to the database.

Below code is how their session is saved.

```
if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

    if (empty($email)) {
        array_push($errors, "email is required");
        echo "Email is required<br>";
    }
    if (empty($password)) {
        array_push($errors, "Password is required");
        echo "Password is required";
    }

    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $password = md5($password); 
        $query = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name2 WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'";
        $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
          $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
          $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
          header('location: store/generatetrans.php');
    }
    else {
        array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
        echo "Wrong username/password combination";
    }
    }
    }
```

They can login using their Email and Password.

```
<?php 
  session_start(); 

  if (!isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first";
    header('location: ../login.php');
  }
  if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION['email']);
    header("location: ../login.php");
  }
?>
```

I used this code for the system to identify who is logged in.

When they are logged in, the system shows "Welcome user@email.com" using this code.

```
<?php  if (isset($_SESSION['email'])) : ?>
      <p>Welcome <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?></strong></p>
      <p> <a href="index.php?logout='1'" style="color: red;">logout</a> </p>
    <?php endif ?>
```

My question is how can I still get the **NAME** that the user used when he/she signed up and show it beside the welcome instead of the email. I still want to use the **$_SESSION['email']** not the name to identify the user . is that possible?

Comment: Store the name in `$_SESSION` as well and/or fetch it from the database…!?

Comment: So I should add the name on the query on how their session is saved?

Comment: I also added the current code on how the session is saved :)

Comment: you're not live with this, are you? or planning on?

Comment: No. Im still on my localhost.

Comment: good, because you will get hacked.

Comment: MD5 is 30+ years old and unsafe now. Use `password_hash() / password_verify()` along with a prepared statement. Don't practice with unsafe code as it produces bad habits.

Comment: Thank you for the tip sir. Ill change that once I uploaded it to the live environment.

Comment: But my question is can I add the name on the query on how my session is saved?

Comment: @Benj I've posted something for you to look at below.

Answer (score 0):

(To help you out).

In your query where you have people login, you are probably doing some type of loop, one such as:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];

}
```

Just add to that:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
    $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];

}
```

You can then use that session array in other pages.

Make sure that each session array is set and not empty and that the session was started.

Edit:

You can also assign a session array to a post array.

I.e. and assuming that `$_POST['login_user']` is what you want to use here:

```
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['login_user'];
```

---

Footnote:

As I stated in comments:

> MD5 is 30+ years old and unsafe now. Use password_hash() / password_verify() along with a prepared statement. Don't practice with unsafe code as it produces bad habits.

So please do yourself a favor and start off on the right foot.

References:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement
- http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php

Comment: `$row['email'] = $_SESSION['email'];` backwards, or just me?

Comment: @IdontDownVote You may be right. I'll edit. Thanks :-)

Comment: its Friday afternoon, i'm never sure about anything on a Friday afternoon.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help sir. But when logging in a user I am not using while loop. I use if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) like the code above.

Comment: @IdontDownVote No worries. I've edited. It's been a while for me on sessions, and they confuse me sometimes.

Comment: @Benj Yes, you can assign a session array to a post array, quite a few ways to do it actually.

Comment: So if I am not using while loop where should I add another session to call the name?

Comment: Using a loop here is a bad example, as you're not interested in *multiple results* at all. While it's a common newbie mistake to use loops when fetching from a database even while it's unnecessary (pun intended), let's not perpetuate that stereotype.

Comment: @deceze I agree (sorry). I posted that before seeing what they had. It is "one" method though. I did add another option though assigning a session array to a post array.

Comment: @Benj you can place it where you have a value for the POST arrays that you have now where you have SESSION arrays.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I only have email and password on my POST arrays. Name is not included. So how can I use that on my SESSION?

Comment: @Benj I see you're using `if (isset($_POST['login_user']))` so I edited my answer in that respect, thinking that that is what you want to use as their name. If not, then you probably won't have a choice *but* to use a loop (which deceze pointed out is a bad idea) and to use the column `name` if there is one and assign a session array to that row's value in a `while` loop. I don't know what your table structure looks like, or if you're actually asking their name on login, but I doubt that. There isn't much else I can add to the answer.

Comment: I am only asking the user's email and password on login. But when signing up, I require them to also add their name. Their name, email, and password are saved in in the columns in the table registeredusers.

Comment: @Benj Presumably you fetch the information from the database when you do the login, no? Get the name from the database while you're at it and store it in `$_SESSION`. Period. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @Benj as I said in my previous comment. Place a loop inside where you have success and assign a session array to the value.